# How to get the min, max, and sum of JSON data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I had JSON data that came back with single int values. With some changes, the values are now coming back as arrays of ints (as well as the original format).

```json
{
  "value": 10,
  "value": 70,
  "value": 30,
  "value": 200
}

- and -

{
  "value": [64, 13, 55, 34, 52, 43, 59, 20, 20],
  "value": [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 70, 60, 40, 50]
}
```

I had a formula that would return the min, max, and sum of the old version of JSON data. Now it doesn't work, and I can't figure out what would be the best way to re-write the function to handle the arrays. Or if its better to make a second function to handle just arrays and do a check if it is an int or array?

Is there a way that would return (from the numbers above):

```
// no value array, apply to all
[ 10, 200, 310 ] // min, max, sum

- and -

// for each of the value arrays
[ 23, 64, 360 ] // val 1 - min, max, sum
[ 10, 90, 450 ] // val 2 - min, max, sum
```

```js
// input data
const value = document.querySelectorAll( "div" ).forEach( el => {

  const contents = el.textContent,      // get the text in the <div>
        json = JSON.parse( contents ),  // parse the data
        jsonData = json.data;           // get the data only

  // normalise the data
  // @from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67294607/1086990
  const normaliseData = arr => {
    const data = arr.map(({ value }) => value);
    return typeof arr[0].value === 'number' ? [data] : data;
  };

  // add into const
  const valueArray = normaliseData( jsonData );


  // get the min / max / sum
  const minMaxSum = valueArray.forEach( e => {
    return [
      Math.min(...e),
      Math.max(...e),
      [...e].reduce((v, w) => v + w)
    ];
  });
  
  // output
  console.log( minMaxSum );
});
```

```html
<div>
  { "data": [ { "value": [64, 23, 45, 34, 52, 43, 59, 40] }, { "value": [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 70, 60, 40, 50] } ] }
</div>

<div>
  { "data": [ { "value": 600 }, { "value": 70 }, { "value": 30 } ] }
</div>
```

Comment: I guess you're lost because you use `reduce` with 20 lines of stuff inside it while a simply 3-lines loop would solve the problem just as well.

Comment: @georg how would you simplify it to 3 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalize the data by testing the type of the value of the first object in each array:

```
const valueInArray = [{ value: [64, 23] }, { value: [45, 34] }];
const valueAsSingle = [{ value: 600 }, { value: 70 }];

const normalizeData = arr => {
  const data = arr.map(({ value }) => value);

  return typeof arr[0].value === 'number'
    ? [data]
    : data;
};

console.log(normalizeData(valueInArray));
//=> [ [ 64, 23 ], [ 45, 34 ] ]

console.log(normalizeData(valueAsSingle));
//=> [ [ 600, 70 ] ]
```

Now they are the same shape, and so you can treat them equally.

Comment: thanks @Corey. I seem to still have issue after the normalisation. If you look here https://codepen.io/markbattistella/pen/jOyJRzG so line 25 and 29 seem to not return the min/max/sum

Comment: @markb `.forEach()` does not return an array. Change it to `.map()` and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Math.max and Math.min to find the maximum and minimum of the array then assign the values in the specific variables.

Currently, when you are using `val.value` it is consisting of the whole array and hence you also need to iterate over the array to find the max, min, or sum.

To find the sum use `reduce` on the val.value array and then add it in the `acc[2]`.

```js
// input data
const valueInArray  = document.getElementById("valueInArray").innerHTML,
      valueAsSingle = document.getElementById("valueAsSingle").innerHTML;

// parse
const jsonArray  = JSON.parse( valueInArray ),
      jsonNumber = JSON.parse( valueAsSingle ),
      jsonArrayData  = jsonArray.data,
      jsonNumberData = jsonNumber.data;


// get numbers
const minMaxSumArray = jsonArrayData.reduce( ( acc, val ) => {
  // smallest number
    acc[0] = (
    ( acc[0] === undefined || Math.min(...val.value) < acc[0] ) ?
      Math.min(...val.value) : acc[0]
    )

    // largest number
    acc[1] = (
    ( acc[1] === undefined || Math.max(...val.value) > acc[1] ) ?
      Math.max(...val.value) : acc[1]
  )

  // sum of numbers
  acc[2] = (
    acc[2] === undefined ?
      val.value.reduce((v, w) => v + w) : val.value.reduce((v, w) => v + w) + acc[2]
  )

  console.log('answer', acc)
  // return the array
  return acc;
}, [] );
```

```html
<div id="valueInArray">
  { "data": [ { "value": [64, 23, 45, 34, 52, 43, 59, 40] }, { "value": [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 70, 60, 40, 50] } ] }
</div>

<div id="valueAsSingle">
  { "data": [ { "value": 10 }, { "value": 70 }, { "value": 30 } ] }
</div>
```

Comment: that seems to work, but maybe i missed it in the original post. it doesn't handle both types of values (single ints over many `value` and array ints)

Answer (score 0):

My take on it: first, create a single Array of all values (either arrays or single) by concatening them and using Array.flat() to flatten it. Then use a reducer to determine the sum and use Math.min/max for the min and max values.

```js
// input data
const valuesInArray  = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector("#valueInArray").textContent).data;
const singleValues  = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector("#valueAsSingle").textContent).data;

// get all values from the objects to a single Array of values
// (so: convert all to single values)
const allValues = valuesInArray.map( v => v.value )
  .concat(singleValues.reduce( (acc, val) => [...acc, +val.value], [] ) )
  .flat();
  
// let's see what we have
console.log(`All values from both objects: ${JSON.stringify(allValues)}`);

// create sum, min and max
const [ sum, min, max, ] = [
  allValues.reduce( (a, v) => a + +v, 0), 
  Math.min(...allValues), 
  Math.max(...allValues) ];
console.log(`From all values sum is ${sum}, min ${min} and max ${max}`);
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="valueInArray">
  { "data": [ 
    { "value": [64, 23, 45, 34, 52, 43, 59, 40] }, 
    { "value": [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 70, 60, 40, 50] } ] 
  }
</div>

<div id="valueAsSingle">
  { "data": 
    [ { "value": 10 }, { "value": 70 }, { "value": 30 } ] 
  }
</div>
```

The second snippet aggregates data per value, where the single values are added as a values array to `valuesInArray`.

```js
// input data
const valuesInArray  = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector("#valueInArray").textContent).data;
const singleValues  = JSON.parse(
  document.querySelector("#valueAsSingle").textContent).data;

// create sum, min and max *per value*, in one go
const aggregatesAdded = valuesInArray
  .concat({ value: singleValues.reduce( (acc, val) => [...acc, +val.value], [] ) } )
  .reduce( (acc, val) => [...acc, {...val, aggregatedValues: {
      sum: val.value.reduce( (a, v) => a + +v, 0 ), 
      min: Math.min(...val.value), 
      max: Math.max(...val.value) } }
    ], [])

document.querySelector("pre").textContent = 
  JSON.stringify({data: aggregatesAdded}, null, 2);
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="valueInArray">
  { "data": [ 
    { "value": [64, 23, 45, 34, 52, 43, 59, 40] }, 
    { "value": [10, 90, 20, 80, 30, 70, 60, 40, 50] } ] 
  }
</div>

<div id="valueAsSingle">
  { "data": 
    [ { "value": 10 }, { "value": 70 }, { "value": 30 } ] 
  }
</div>

<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: sorting an array to get its min/max is a waste of cycles.

Comment: Ok, let's use Math.min/max then. Although I suspect Math.min/max to cycle too, but supposedly more optimized. [See the V8 code](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/cd81dd6d740ff82a1abbc68615e8769bd467f91e/src/js/math.js#L77-L102)

Comment: @KooiInc without merging all the numbers, how would i use this to handle only the individual `data` strings? so if the values were passed as `valueInArray` format it would get the min, max, sum of each value array. if the values were passed as `valueAsSingle ` it would get the min, max, sum out of all the individual ints

Comment: @markb Maybe the second snippet helps you with that?

Comment: @KooiInc it does, only you are still merging all the values. I'm trying to isolate them per json - https://codepen.io/markbattistella/pen/jOyJRzG. I want to pass either types and it works on it both ways

Comment: Without merging: check [this @ codeblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-so-67279489?file=index.js). You now shouldbe able to figure it out for yourself ...